# warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted

Tags: 12.10, code-blocks, gdb

I'm using Code-Blocks IDE in my Ubuntu 12.10.But when I'm trying to debug any project, I got the following warning:

```
warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted
```

What should I do now ?

Comment: Search in the settings of CodeBlocks if you can change the terminal type.

Comment: On a side note, if your current instruction arrow is not showing this error is NOT the cause. I spent hours trying to get the current instruction arrow to show thinking that this warning was causing it and not finding anything on google searches. In my case it was because I was using the wrong debugging format in nasm, I switched to using dwarf instead and it worked.

Comment: https://rr-project.org/

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem on Ubuntu 16.04 using GDB 7.11 via XTerm. To solve it I simply modified the permissions on the local .gdbinit file by issuing `chmod +x /path/to/file/.gdbinit` which resolved the issue.

Comment: Does not work to fix this error.

Answer (score 3):

1. Install or verify that gnome terminal is installed on your PC
2. Switch to `gnome-terminal`. under Settings -> Environment -> Terminal to launch, I use this:

   ```
   gnome-terminal --disable-factory --hide-menubar -t $TITLE -x
   ```

You will still get the error but the debugger works completely.

Comment: As you mention, that doesn't solve the error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Problem with Ubuntu 10.04, QTCreator 2.5.2 and gdb 7.1 coming with ubuntu.

I could solve my problems with an upgrade to the current version 7.5 of gdb and using this instead the 7.1 installed by ubuntu.

You can download the latest and compile it by yourself:

- Check for the latest `gdb-*.tar.gz` file [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/?C=M;O=D), and adapt the commands below if necessary.

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-7.6.2.tar.gz
tar xvfz gdb-7.6.2.tar.gz
cd gdb-7.6.2
./configure
make
cp gdb/gdb /usr/local/bin
```

Take care about that the `/usr/local/bin` is at the beginning of the PATH you are using while running QtCreator.

You can place the following line into your `.profile`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using KDBG on Debian jessie to debug assembling program but it was only because I didn't have the right to execute the file (copy)

a simple `chmod +x /path/to/file` solved the problem

Comment: what exactly would we put in for /path/to/file what file are we looking for?

Comment: the executable.. the thing you're debugging.

Comment: That won't help this problem. gdb will be doing something like `ioctl(TIOCSCTTY)` and failing because the terminal is already controlling another session.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem using Debug in kdevelop with my C code. Disdabled the "Use External Terminal" option under Run/Configure Launches and it works like a charm.